# Why isn't this sed regex matching?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I've recently started learning `sed`. I did

```
$seq 10 | sed '/[^049]/d'
```

I was expecting

```
4 
9
10
```

as output. But I got

```
4
9
```

Where am I making mistake in understanding this regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `1` in the number `10` matches `[^049]` so it's deleted.

Comment: Whoops. That was foolish of me to ask here. :( Thanks by the way.

Comment: Minor tip: Bracketing your regex with `^` and `$` is useful to ensure that you're always looking at the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to show lines containing '0', '4', or '9', here's how:

```
seq 10 | sed -n '/[049]/p'
```

The `-n` instructs `sed` to *not* print any lines. The `p` command instructs `sed` to print lines matching the `/regex/`

Alternatively, you can always use `grep` :-)

```
seq 10 | grep -E "[049]"
```

Comment: This is valid, but the exact approach the OP was looking for was probably: `seq 10 | sed '/[049]/!d'`  This deletes any lines that do *not* match `[049]` rather than deleting any lines which match "not 049", aka `[^049]`.